# Some syntax clarification: ${*$sock}

Tags: perl, sockets, object

I am looking into the IO:Socket.pm module and I see the first time the "*$sock" notation.

```
sub socket {
    @_ == 4 or croak 'usage: $sock->socket(DOMAIN, TYPE, PROTOCOL)';
    my($sock,$domain,$type,$protocol) = @_;

    socket($sock,$domain,$type,$protocol) or
        return undef;

    ${*$sock}{'io_socket_domain'} = $domain;
    ${*$sock}{'io_socket_type'}   = $type;
    ${*$sock}{'io_socket_proto'}  = $protocol;

    $sock;
}
```

What is the intent of the following syntax ?

```
${*$sock}{'io_socket_domain'} = $domain;
```

Especially I am referring to the asterisk notation ... $sock is an object as far I understand but what is this thing: ${*$sock} ? And how is this asterisk operator called and its purpose?

I would be grateful if someone can make me see with some practical minimalistic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary: because filehandles (and hence socket filehandles in this case) are GLOB refs and not HASH refs. You can't simply

```
$sock->{field}
```

because that would only work if $sock is a `HASH` reference. Instead, for `GLOB`-based objects we use the hash slot of the underlying glob as a place to store the object instance fields

```
   $sock       # is a GLOB reference
  *$sock       # is the underlying GLOB
%{*$sock}      # is the hash at the HASH slot of the GLOB
${*$sock}{key} # is a member of the HASH
```

Answer (score 1):

`IO::Handle` (and therefore `IO::Socket`, `IO::File`, etc) returns a blessed [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) reference from its constructor. This allows the object itself to be used as a filehandle, as in:

```
use IO::File;

$fh = IO::File->new();
if ($fh->open("< file")) {
    print <$fh>;
    $fh->close;
}
```

In `IO::Socket`, the blessed typeglob also holds a hash. `${*$sock}{'io_socket_domain'}` is dereferencing the typeglob (just like `@$arrayref` would dereference an array reference) then accessing this hash.